# Adjust code style Settings : dart android studio and i am not getting any error suggestions and code format suggestions

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

[the box I am being taken to when I clicked on Adjust code style settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEziD.png)

[I am taken here when I click on blub icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMCPz.png)

this is happening from the time updated by the android studio to the new update(Bumble bee 2021.1.1 patch 1)

Comment: Can You Be More Specific? Whats the issue?

Comment: AFAIK Dart autoformat is not adjustable except for the length of line.

Comment: Getting same thing. and I am not getting the normal contextual options.